# Ask about convert a video file?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Where i can ask about problem in converting a video file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Super User has quite a few [questions on video conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion), so provided you've posted all the relevant details & your question isn't a "which codec is best for this" question, it should fit well.

Make sure you read the [tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/video-conversion/info) and go through some of the [existing questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion) before asking though.